# Which sentence correctly uses the verb "stand"?

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure which sentence is normal or how they differ.

1. The lighthouse was standing on a cliff.
2. The lighthouse stood on a cliff.

Which one can I use? Also, is the *stood* in sentence number two a “state”?

Comment: It depends on the context. Either one is fine.

Comment: With the first, I would wonder if the lighthouse was accustomed to standing somewhere else, and had decided to take a walk to the cliff, e.g. to admire the sea view.

Comment: ... Yes, as Michael says, even though 'was standing' is stative, it certainly suggests an impermanent state. 'Before the incredible engineering feat of moving it half a mile inland was accomplished, the lighthouse was standing on a cliff' is a less tongue-in-cheek contextualisation.

Comment: And actually [that's been done](https://www.ice.org.uk/what-is-civil-engineering/what-do-civil-engineers-do/moving-the-belle-tout-lighthouse) although it was only 17 metres in that particular case.

Answer (score 1):

> The lighthouse was standing on a cliff.
>
> The lighthouse stood on a cliff.

As always, it depends on context. Neither of those sentences would be said or written without background information. You have used "the" so this means that the lighthouse has been mentioned before.

I'll just go for the most obvious meanings.

*The lighthouse was standing on a cliff. Then it gave a great cry of despair and leaped into the sea below.*

*The lighthouse stood on a cliff. From there it could be seen by ships many miles away.*